# Java program one process per user on Microsoft Server

Tags: java, jvm, multiprocessing, windows-server-2012-r2

I receive bug to fix. Somebody write program which call printing document from other app. Jar with this program is on microsoft server for a few users. Problem is when one of user want print and other too in the same moment. Fox example user1 click print and have print preview, at the same moment user2 do the same action and he don't have print preview, because print prieview of document user2 is displayed on screen user1. I don't know where is bug. Maybe main app call the same instance of jar or the use the same process. Here is my code of method which is called when user click print.

```
public void openCreatedFile() {
        String filePath = "file:///" + findNewlyCreatedFile().replace("\\", "/");
        try {
            if (xContext != null)
                System.out.println("Opening file ...");
            xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();


            Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);

            xCLoader = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader.class, oDesktop);
            com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[] szEmptyArgs = new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0];

            xComp = xCLoader.loadComponentFromURL(filePath, "_blank", 0, szEmptyArgs);
            System.out.println(filePath);
            xDoc = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument.class, xComp);
            xContext = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            Thread.currentThread();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `findNewlyCreatedFile`, `xCLoader` , `xDoc`, `xComp`, `xContext`, `szEmptyArgs`  and `xMCF` seem to be shared members which should be synchronized.

By the looks of this snipped, we don't know the rest of it, this code is not concurrency safe at all.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap socket connection?

Comment: Yes, something like this `libre.xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(libre.oooExeFolder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your BootstrapSocketConnector. Here is solution:

```
for(int i = 8100; i<=65535 ; i++){
                if(available(i)){
                    libre.xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(libre.oooExeFolder, "localhost", i);
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
                    }
            }
```

8100 is for example, here you must use your port which is using to connection. 
And for example method `available()` where you check closest available port:

```
private static boolean available(int port) {
        try{
        Socket ignored = new Socket("localhost", port);
            return false;
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```